# Reading input files with ASCII 215 as delimiter

Tags: python, file, input, delimiter

I am trying to read from a file which has word pairs delimited by ASCII value 215. When I run the following code:

```
f = open('file.i', 'r')
for line in f.read().split('×'):
    print line
```

I get a string that looks like garbage. Here is a sample of my input:

```
abashedness×N
abashment×N
abash×t
abasia×N
abasic×A
abasing×t
Abas×N
abatable×A
abatage×N
abated×V
abatement×N
abater×N
Abate×N
abate×Vti
abating×V
abatis×N
abatjours×p
abatjour×N
abator×N
abattage×N
abattoir×N
abaxial×A
```

and here is my output after the code above is run:

```
z?Nlner?N?NANus?A?hion?hk?hhn?he?hanoconiosis?N
```

My goal is to eventually read this into either a list of tuples or something of that nature, but I'm having trouble just getting the data to print.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: What does `print repr(line)` produce?

Comment: There's no such thing as ASCII value 215. It's a byte with no meaning in the ASCII encoding.

Comment: @user2357112: it is not even a byte. `'×'` is two bytes in utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two things:

- Your source could be Unicode! Use an escape and be safe.
- Read in binary mode.

```
with open("file.i", "rb") as f:
    for line in f.read().split(b"\xd7"):
        print(line)
```

Comment: Please, don't call source 'Unicode'. It could be using an *encoding* that from the Unicode standard, but that doesn't make it Unicode. It'd make it UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32, at best.

Comment: `b'×'` is `b'\xc3\x97'` (utf-8 source code encoding). Input file may have different encoding than the script.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, it could be any of those, and it would break all of those. Hence, Unicode.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The asker specified ASCII

Comment: @minitech: the asker is confused. The answerer should know that `×` is not ascii.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: People extend ASCII differently… I’m not familiar with Windows stuff, e.g.

Comment: ASCII is ASCII. Once you extend beyond it you are no longer using *just* ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

The character is delimiting the word and the part of speech, but each word is still on its own line:

```
with open('file.i', 'rb') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        word, pos = line.strip().split('×')

        print word, pos
```

Your code was splitting the *whole* file, so you were ending up with words like `N\nabatable`, `N\nAbate`, `Vti\nabating`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both your help, I was able to hack together this bit of code that returns a list of lists holding what I'm looking for.

```
with open("mobyposi.i", "rb") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    content = content[0].split()
    for item in content:
        item.split("\xd7")
```

It was indeed in unicode! However, the implementation described above discarded the text after the unicode value and before the newline.

EDIT: Able to reduce to:

```
with open("mobyposi.i", "rb") as f:
    for item in f.read().split():
        item.split("\xd7")
```

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. `f.readlines()` returns a list of lines. `content[0]` is the first line. `.split()` tries to split the line on whitespace. There is none between the word pair in the line so it returns the line as a list with the only item -- the 1st line itself. Then you call `.split("\xd7")` with a byte argument (it is in utf-8 the 2nd byte of `×` character i.e., you would split inside a character in this case) and you don't use the result in the end. Also `with`-statement closes the file, don't call `f.close()` yourself.

Comment: What if I promise I get what I wanted? f.readlines() returns: `"['abashedness\xd7N\rabashment\xd7N\rabash\xd7t\rabasia\xd7N\rabasic\xd7A\rabasing\xd7t\rAbas\xd7N\rabatable\xd7A\rabatage\xd7N\rabated\xd7V\rabatement\xd7N\rabater\xd7N\rAbate\xd7N\rabate\xd7Vti\rabating\xd7V\rabatis\xd7N\rabatjours\xd7p\rabatjour\xd7N\rabator\xd7N\rabattage\xd7N\rabattoir\xd7N\rabaxial\xd7A']"`


Then I use content = content[0].split()

Comment: Your data uses Carriage Return `\r` as a newline. If you open the file as binary; `\r` won't be recognized as a newline. It is pointless to call `f.readlines()` in this case. Have you tried [the code from my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20591378/4279) with `cp1252` encoding? Given the data it is not the only possible character encoding but it works on this particular sample.

Answer (score 0):

To interpret bytes from a file as text, you need to know its character encoding. [There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). You could use `codecs` module to read the text:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('file.i', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file: 
     for line in file:
         word, sep, suffix = line.partition(u'\u00d7')
         if sep:
            print word
```

Put the actual character encoding of the file instead of `utf-8` placeholder e.g., `cp1252`.

Non-ascii characters in string literals would require source character encoding declaration at the top the script so I've used the unicode escape: `u'\u00d7'`.